# How to update a function with previous iterate?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-value, iteration

I'm trying to solve a differential equation numerically, and it has led me to a non-linear system of equations which I wish to solve using Newton's Method, which, for systems, is given by (for 3 equations in 3 unknowns, specifically),

$x_{1}^{(k+1)}=x_{1}^{(k)}-\omega\frac{f_{1}(x_{1}^{(k)},x_{2}^{(k)},x_{3}^{(k)})}{\frac{\partial f_{1}}{x_{1}}(x_{1}^{(k)},x_{2}^{(k)},x_{3}^{(k)})}$

$x_{2}^{(k+1)}=x_{2}^{(k)}-\omega\frac{f_{2}(x_{1}^{(k+1)},x_{2}^{(k)},x_{3}^{(k)})}{\frac{\partial f_{2}}{x_{2}}(x_{1}^{(k+1)},x_{2}^{(k)},x_{3}^{(k)})}$

$x_{3}^{(k+1)}=x_{3}^{(k)}-\omega\frac{f_{3}(x_{1}^{(k+1)},x_{2}^{(k+1)},x_{3}^{(k)})}{\frac{\partial f_{3}}{x_{3}}(x_{1}^{(k+1)},x_{2}^{(k+1)},x_{3}^{(k)})}$

for the $k^{th}$ iteration. Here is part of my code,

```
Newt = FixedPointList[{#[[1]] - \[Omega] (
      f[[1]] /. {y2 -> #[[1]], y3 -> #[[2]], y4 -> #[[3]]})/
      f'[[1]], #[[2]] - \[Omega] (
      f[[2]] /. {y2 -> #[[1]], y3 -> #[[2]], y4 -> #[[3]]})/
      f'[[1]], #[[3]] - \[Omega] (
      f[[3]] /. {y2 -> #[[1]], y3 -> #[[2]], y4 -> #[[3]]})/
      f'[[1]]} &, {1.4, 3.7, 2.7}]
```

I've previously defined f and $\omega$ in a necessary manner and this converges to give me a solution to the system. However, in the second and third functions I have defined in this iteration (I've defined a total of three), I have been unable to figure out how to replace `#[[2]]` in the second function and `#[[2]]`,`#[[3]]` in the third with $x_{1}^{(k+1)}$ and $x_{1}^{(k+1)},x_{2}^{(k+1)}$, respectively.

Also, I'm more interested in implementing `NestWhileList` to carry out this procedure, but cannot figure out how to give the appropriate test to stop the iteration. I wish for $|x_{1}^{(k+1)}-x_{1}^{(k)}|<10^{-5}$ and similarly for the other variables. But I am unsure how to do this when defining multiple functions of multiple variables within `NestWhileList`.

I am a beginner, so I don't have much experience, but I am learning how to become more handy with mathematica by reading incredibly helpful forums and literature and I would appreciate if anybody could provide me with any help, hints or tips regarding the issues I'm having.

Comment: As you do not give w and f, a final answer is not possible. But you do not need any replace. Define functions e.g. fi and give #1,#2.. as arguments like f1[#1,#2,..] or even simpler: f1[##] . ## is a sequence that will evaöluate to f1[#1,#2,,..]

Comment: Thanks again @Daniel Huber, I appreciate your help! I defined w = 1 and f has been defined and given as a list in my program. This gives me the system of equations necessary for which Newton's Method must be applied. I believe I've tried something like that.. so that I could just put f1 in place of `#[[1]]` in the second function of `Newt`, for example, if I'm thinking correctly .. but in defining fi separately in the manner you've indicated (which I believe I've tried independently), I found that my original attempt no longer works and mathematica remains in the state of "(Running...)".

Comment: If you define fun as: fun := # - 
   w {f1[#]/D[f1[#], #[[1]]], f2[#]/D[f2[#], #[[2]]], 
     f3[#]/D[f3[#], #[[3]]]} &    and    f1[{x1_,x2_,x3_}]:= .. You can give fun directly  to NestWhileList. For the stop criterion, you must save the last 2 values of x1: NestWileList[fun,{StartValues},Abs[x1old1-x1old2]>10^-5]

Comment: Thanks much for that advice @Daniel Huber, I will put it to good use. As for saving the last two values of x1 during the iteration, that is precisely what I am having trouble with and have spent some good time trying to figure out. How could I go about saving those?

Comment: To save the last 2 values of x1, you may define an array old with 2 elements in the context of NestWhileList. Inside fun or f1 you then say e.g. f1[{x1_,x2_,x3_}]:=(new= ...; old={old[[2]],new}; new)